# Marker position is changing based on the device screen width

Tags: android, android-canvas

In my application,I am setting an image in my imageview. I just need to place a marker on that imageview. I am doing it with onDraw function in my custom image view class.The problem is,for example if I take x position and y position as 40 respectively.The marker position shown above image in my mobile is different when compared with running same application on tablet.

I want a solution such that when I give coordinates then the position of marker on image in mobile and tablet appears same.

Here is the code my main activity:

```
public class PointOnImageActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_point_on_image);
        CustomImag ev= new CustomImag(this);
        ev.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stad);// set background
        setContentView(ev);
    }
}
```

Here is the code of my custom imageview class:

```
public class CustomImag extends ImageView
{
        public CustomImag(Context context) 
        {
        super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
        {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawCircle(40,40,10,mPaint);
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

that's because 40 is pixel value, you actually need 40dp instead. so you can convert 40dp to px value dynamically, like this:

```
int pxValue1 = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40,  context.getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics());

int pxValue2 = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10,  context.getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics());


 canvas.drawCircle(pxValue,pxValue,pxValue2,mPaint);
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it's not working. Still it's showing the marker in different position, when I tried with phone and tablet

Answer (score 1):

You have to position your custom `View` according to the screen dimensions. This way, no matter what size screen displays your app, your positioning will be relative.

In your `onDraw(Canvas)` method, you can get the screen dimensions and draw the circle using them. In the following example(which is mostly your code), I place the red circle at `screen_width / 4` and `screen_height / 4`:

```
public class MyCustomImageViewActivity extends Activity{    

    CustomImag ev;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ev = new CustomImag(this);
        ev.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stad);// set background
        setContentView(ev);
    }

    public class CustomImag extends ImageView {
        Paint mPaint;

        public CustomImag(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mPaint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Point point = new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);

        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(point.x / 4, point.y / 4, 10, mPaint);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I guess this is for showing the marker only at the center. What if we need to do it in a different position?

Comment: @roymathew What position do you want to display it in?

Comment: Sorry for the above comment, it was a mistake from my side. But I have tried your code and marker is coming in different positions when I tried with a mobile and a tablet. I need to fix it in a position, even if the device changes.

Comment: @roymathew Your original code should work fine if you want to show the marker at **exactly** the same position on every device. Not sure why it isn't.

Comment: In emulator and phone it looks similar, but in tablet it is showing the marker in a different position.